# Background location service notification has a blank notification small icon

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, geolocation, icons

I'm trying to build an app which uses the flutter location package to continuously get the user's location.

Only problem is, the notification that says "Background location service running" has a blank space where the application icon should be.

I get FCM notifications just fine with the icon showing and everything.

[Picture showing blank icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItfVG.jpg)
[Picture showing blank icon2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9JOt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

first you should have to fill the OAuth consent form into the google cloud console. there you can set logo of the application.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

Comment: Not very helpful. The problem is rather local.

Comment: have you add your icon into that consent form?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the plugin itself.

[The part that must be changed in the android plugin](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/blob/439ae1b49375ccf9016086206e3c344ff04ee230/location/android/src/main/java/com/lyokone/location/FlutterLocationService.kt#L125)

I changed the plugin in my pub-cache from:

```
val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.navigation_empty_icon)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .build()
```

To

```
val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("You can change the title to whatever here")
                    .setSmallIcon("@mipmap/ic_launcher", "mipmap", packageName))
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .build()
```

This will make the title whatever you want and the icon same as the application's

Answer (score 0):

in the version 4.3.0 ..\packages\location\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt

change the line 21 from

```
const val kDefaultNotificationIconName: String = "navigation_empty_icon"
```

to

```
const val kDefaultNotificationIconName: String = "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```